# CBC-MAC implementation in C

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, cbc-mode, cbc-mac

I'm hoping to do some benchmarking of CBC-MAC in C. Does anyone know of a robust C implementation? I've looked around but CBC-MAC implementations (in almost any language) seem to be quite rare. Does anyone know why beside its rather restrictive (desired) use cases, e.g., fixed-length input.

Thanks

Comment: CMAC simply extends CBC-MAC and is secure for variable sized input. Why would you use CBC-MAC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you encrypt a message with a **block cipher** in **CBC mode** with a **zero Initialization Vector**, then the last encrypted block, is the **CBC-MAC**.

So if you have a **block cipher** implementation that supports **CBC mode**, you basically have support for **CBC-MAC**.

Comment: Are you sure? Doesn't the last block encrypted block have to be identical to the first encrypted block?